# spring boot API + security +ldap

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-security, ldap

I want to achieve LDAP verification without form login, But not sure how to achieve it.

**EDITED:** I have a custom POST API /login which accept userId and password and validate it and creates a session cookies/Token.

Few doubts:

1. how to point to custom login URL endpoint?
2. How internally the form login used to validate the cookie once we successfully validated the credentials? How to achieve the same with custom login endpoint?
3. Do i have to change something in CRSF?

```java
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    
    @Autowired
    private LdapProperties ldapProperties;
    @Bean
    public LdapAuthenticationProvider
    authenticationProvider(final LdapAuthenticator authenticator) {
        return new LdapAuthenticationProvider(authenticator);
    }

   
    @Bean
    public BindAuthenticator authenticator(final BaseLdapPathContextSource contextSource) {
        final BindAuthenticator authenticator = new BindAuthenticator(contextSource);
        authenticator.setUserDnPatterns(new String[] {
                ldapProperties.getUserDnPatterns() });
        return authenticator;
    }

    
    @Override
    public void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.ldapAuthentication().userSearchFilter(ldapProperties.getSearchFilter())
        .contextSource(contextSource());
    }

    
    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .csrf()
        .disable()
        .formLogin().and() 
        .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and().logout()
        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/login");

    }

   
    @Override
    public void configure(final WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.debug(true);
    }

    
    @Bean
    public LdapContextSource contextSource() {
        final LdapContextSource contextSource = new LdapContextSource();
        contextSource.setUrl(ldapProperties.getUrl());
        contextSource.setBase(ldapProperties.getBase());
        contextSource.setUserDn(ldapProperties.getUserDn());
        contextSource.setPassword(ldapProperties.getUserDnPaswrd());
        contextSource.setPooled(true);
        contextSource.afterPropertiesSet();
        return contextSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LdapTemplate ldapTemplate() {
        final LdapTemplate ldapTemplate = new LdapTemplate(
            contextSource());
        ldapTemplate.setIgnorePartialResultException(true);
        return ldapTemplate;
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not understanding what you mean by "without form login". Your sample code is using form login. Can you elaborate? How do you want to get the credentials from the end user?

Comment: @jzheaux 
Edited in the question : 
I have a custom POST API /login which accept userId and password and validate it and creates a session cookies/Token.

Comment: Spring Security already does all of that for you. Can you explain why you want to process the u/p yourself and why you want to issue the session cookie and token yourself?